# python: how to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of structure tensor?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensor, eigenvalue, eigenvector

In a for loop where I iterate over the image size I calculate the 2D structure tensor for each pixel:

```
tensor = np.array([[pixel_image_1, pixel_image_3], [pixel_image_3, pixel_imgage_2]])
```

where convolution happens like this:

```
pixel_image_1 = Gaussian * ux^2 (at [i,j])
pixel_image_2 = Gaussian * uy^2 (at [i,j])
pixel_image_3 = Gaussian * ux x uy (at [i,j])
```

Next I need the einenvectors(`v1,v2`)/eigenvalues(`mu1,mu2`) of the structure tensor

I found out that I can calculate the eigenvectors/eigenvalues like the following:

```
eigenvalue, eigenvector = np.linalg.eig(tensor)
```

I do not understand how to extract (`v1,v2`), (`mu1,mu2`) out of eigenvalue, eigenvector?

Could someone help me here pls?

Comment: The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) is pretty clear about how to interpret the outputs. What is your difficulty? Please be explicit!

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you for this advice I already checked your link to the docu. The assignment-description tells me that I need two eigenvalues and two eigenvectors {{mu1,mu2},{v1,v2}} = eig(tensor) but as far as I understood it right numpy.linalg.eig(tensor) returns 2 eigenvalues and 4 eigenvectors in case of a 2x2 matrix? Sry, if this problem is trivial to you I am quite new to that stuff

Comment: The documentation says “The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i].” This means that your 2x2 matrix is 2 eigenvectors, because it has 2 columns.

Comment: Maybe review the basic concepts of linear algebra, without that understanding it will be very hard for you to continue with your exercise here.